# Mercurial: don't manage as a project

Tags: mercurial

SmartSVN allows you to perform a checkout, that will not be managed by it. Does mercurial have a command that will only checkout a specific revision,  discarding all commits before it?

Comment: clone the repository and delete the `.hg` directory ;) don't know if there are better alternatives

Comment: yes, but for big repositories you would have to download a lot of unnecesary data

Comment: I don't think you have another choise, only if you have a web-frontend in front of your repository which allows you to do a simple download of the current head. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mercurial does not have a command that will let you checkout a single revision from a remote repository. If the repository is local, them see the archive command.

However, most webservers lest you download any revision as a zip or tar file. For the normal hgweb you use URLs like this:

> https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/tip.zip

and for Bitbucket you use URLs like this:

> https://bitbucket.org/mirror/mercurial/get/tip.zip

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the necessary permissions, a straight copy will work:

```
rsync --exclude .hg [user@host:]/path/to/hg/repo mycopy
```

Comment: That will only work if the working directory is updated to the revision one wants. Might work for some circumstances, but not for some server-hosted repositories.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [archive](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Make_a_clean_copy_of_a_source_tree.2C_like_CVS_export) command.