# Git: pull from repository, remotely

Tags: git, pull

I'm locally working on a project, and pushing everything to a remote repository. I've recently found that my hosting provider offers a git client, so instead of generating and applying patches once in a while (I've SSH access) I could use that. Cloning the repository isn't the good way because:

1. It copies the whole thing every time;
2. Some files are edited after the copy (a couple of configurations).

What would be the best way to do this?

(Is there a way to have just the files without the `.git` folder?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into shallow clone. Something like this:

```
git clone --depth <n> <url>
```

with a post-receive hook on the server to edit the configurations.

Check out [shallow cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial) and [git hooks](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).
Some combination of those should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I think this could make the job.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get this, but is this what you're looking for?

```
git archive HEAD | gzip > export.tar.gz
```

Comment: No, but thank you anyway. I'm looking for a way to checkout a repository from another location, updating the new files.

Comment: Your question is rather fuzzy. By checkout you mean? I'm pretty sure you're not using git terminology.

Comment: Sorry, I actually mean ‘pull’.