# How do you copy individual files (or many at once) from your Git repository to your home machine?

Tags: git, github, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you use Git to retrieve just one (or a few) files from a repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004508/how-do-you-use-git-to-retrieve-just-one-or-a-few-files-from-a-repo)

There is a file I'd like to copy from my Git repository into my home machine, but using

```
    git clone ...
```

only lets me copy the whole repository, not individual files.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)