# Do mercurial respositories have to be cloned entirely or can I get subtrees?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I migrated a subversion repository to mercurial. The svn repository contains several projects which are located in different places on my local system. I can't figure out how I'm supposed to work that way. It appears that mercurial expects that I will always want to check out the entire tree into one spot.

Is it possible to check out only a specific subtree?

If not, then I'll need to somehow import parts of my single subversion repository into multiple mercurial repositories. How would I go about doing that (without losing history information from subversion of course).

Comment: Mercurial (and other DVCSes) tend to not support subtree checkouts, yes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial does not support checking out subtrees.  The [ConvertExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) (included with Mercurial) is used to convert repositories, and can also be used to perform filtering where users, files and directories can be remapped or trimmed.  See specifically the `--filemap` option for including/excluding specific branches from the source repository.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mark, **convert** extension can do the job as explained [on its wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial), so to convert a subdirectory "subfoo" of a repository "foo" into repository of its own do this:

```
echo include subfoo > filemap.txt
echo rename subfoo . >> filemap.txt
hg convert --filemap filemap.txt path/to/foo newsubfoo-repo
```

Another tool that can help you with various repository conversions is **[reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/).**

There is also a brand new **[narrowng](https://bitbucket.org/Google/narrowhg)** extension to do this thing, but it is not clear yet if it is production ready.