# Is there anyway to clone only the latest state of a mercurial repository?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Essentially I to get just the contents of the repository at the `default` commit. Conceptually similar to `--depth=1` with git I think.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587100/392949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify up to which commit (from start to commit #5) You want to get the content. 
The thing is - that Mercurial stores all the commits - as DIFFs.

This means - that if You want to get the latest state of the file1.txt, so what mercurial essentially does - is takes the file, as it was added, and applies all the diffs (deltas) onto that.

Basically - You can NOT get half of the repository, because of that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to clone a repository and only get default, but I think 'hg archive' might be close to what you want?

Comment: It's also supported by many Mercurial hosting facilities. For hgweb, the archive capability needs to be specifically enabled, though.