# Why does one call `git read-tree` after a sparse checkout

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

According to [Subdirectory Checkouts with git sparse-checkout](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) one calls `git read-tree -mu HEAD` after configuring a sparse checkout in the case of an already existing repository, i.e.:

```
# Enable sparse-checkout:
git config core.sparsecheckout true

# Configure sparse-checkout 
echo some/dir/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo another/sub/tree >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

# Update your working tree:
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

- Can you please explain the `read-tree` step in more detail?
- How does it work?
- What is going on?
- Why does one use `read-tree` and not, let us say, `checkout`?
- Why does one use `-mu` (why is this a merge, and what is merged)?

> -m
>
> ```
>     Perform a merge, not just a read. The command will refuse to run if
>     your index file has unmerged entries, indicating that you have not
>     finished previous merge you started.
> ```
>
> -u
>
> ```
>     After a successful merge, update the files in the work tree with the
>     result of the merge.
> ```

Comment: Note: with Git 2.27, Q2 2020, `git read-tree` will no longer be called by git sparse-checkout. See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515444/6309)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), Management of sparsely checked-out working tree has gained a dedicated "sparse-checkout" command.
It introduces a cone mode (that I detail in "[Git sparse checkout with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9572407/6309)"), which will make a `sparse-checkout` must faster.

But it also indirectly describes why `git read-tree -mu HEAD` is used (or, with the new "cone" mode, *was* used).

See [commit e6152e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6152e35ff287ab58e2c17065f02cb1be9f4a0aa) (21 Nov 2019) by [Jeff Hostetler (`Jeff-Hostetler`)](https://github.com/Jeff-Hostetler).
See [commit 761e3d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/761e3d26bbe44c51f83c4f1ad198461f57029ebd) (20 Dec 2019) by [Ed Maste (`emaste`)](https://github.com/emaste).
See [commit 190a65f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/190a65f9db8db9d87d54351429f7879fcb4ad608) (13 Dec 2019), and [commit cff4e91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cff4e9138d8df45e3b6199171092ee781cdadaeb), [commit 416adc8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/416adc8711d16c5231693f19ca483dd3d59bef5d), [commit f75a69f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f75a69f88099689b510c7a7261d637bc7004a749), [commit fb10ca5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb10ca5b54362e6f860e1e9049e03924fcf5f05b), [commit 99dfa6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/99dfa6f9702ee81c44ef9382933e4e391ec5d6ee), [commit e091228](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e091228e17e88b1bc16cb50d5c3aff10dc5119d1), [commit e9de487](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9de487aa36aa75b5c9068c6bd07cfb8bf2ee955), [commit 4dcd4de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dcd4def3ca46fc0e8cb28cbfc815a35dd2c3f1d), [commit eb42fec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb42feca974a333e58c2ca0f3cfa8bf0dd421402), [commit af09ce2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af09ce24a9c79f6efc12d1d8f1052e1d1dbe5016), [commit 96cc8ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96cc8ab5318cd57c8bc203b8f064b35883b2386f), [commit 879321e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/879321eb0bec25779386445d65242452825155be), [commit 72918c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72918c1ad91504f56c395cc91c5072651125662a), [commit 7bffca9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7bffca95ea1ca4f55663374ea9b929b9df5be04b), [commit f6039a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6039a9423d042d61fb4cfccb395bd04c4bd5322), [commit d89f09c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d89f09c8289a764f0a974e02bd5b38cf60d1a7d7), [commit bab3c35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bab3c3590879c5680060a5d5e2b93b4f97519025), [commit 94c0956](https://github.com/git/git/commit/94c0956b60969bbbb3ead19638d52591a59d713c) (21 Nov 2019) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bd72a08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd72a08d6ce451e7d4725d6b3b411d482333e5cb), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`sparse-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e091228e17e88b1bc16cb50d5c3aff10dc5119d1): update working directory in-process
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The sparse-checkout builtin used '`git read-tree -mu HEAD`' to update the skip-worktree bits in the index and to update the working directory.
> This extra process is overly complex, and prone to failure. It also requires that we write our changes to the sparse-checkout file before trying to update the index.
>
> Remove this extra process call by creating a direct call to `unpack_trees()` in the same way '`git read-tree -mu HEAD`' does.
> In addition, provide an in-memory list of patterns so we can avoid reading from the sparse-checkout file. This allows us to test a proposed change to the file before writing to it.
>
> An earlier version of this patch included a bug when the '`set`' command failed due to the "Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory" error.
> It would not rollback the `index.lock` file, so the replay of the old sparse-checkout specification would fail. A test in t1091 now covers that scenario.

---

And, with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`sparse-checkout`" knows how to *reapply* itself:

See [commit 5644ca2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5644ca28cded68972c74614fc06d6e0e1db1a7de), [commit 681c637](https://github.com/git/git/commit/681c637b4ae1c46c09edda62a1aed6eaa69a2649), [commit ebb568b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebb568b9e2539ce2dbb3853ff3d4869a5c690601), [commit 22ab0b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22ab0b37d85080d8932e992e183b2f86e67bff19), [commit 6271d77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6271d77cb1ccfb7e4124593b4463446fe1188cda), [commit 1ac83f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac83f42da6437d74098f162fcfa37474c94e223), [commit cd002c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd002c15611a995a29b9e5881745bba402d63952), [commit 4ee5d50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ee5d50fc39f8d41f67c3c9a936084fb914c9a50), [commit f56f31a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f56f31af0301f6446f8689ba1a997d74fb82f45f), [commit 7af7a25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7af7a25853cb87f34d192ba1d813ca09ee15d9f4), [commit 30e89c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30e89c12f0afc5c4382b531973a5e82b60d402bd), [commit 3cc7c50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cc7c50402ce1cbac9735da64844eb00bc096f46), [commit b0a5a12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a5a12a60393237f98ec4b0fcf2b7d3c3232a2a), [commit 72064ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72064ee578a59d4511cab17496c5246af02397f3), [commit fa0bde4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa0bde45cdebee8bac95e66e4bf5ba16c77fbdba), [commit d61633a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61633ae186d26ab2c216108c917ec0ae7dd2782), [commit d7dc1e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7dc1e1668fcbd5af019d0bc059b8dcb35743c86), [commit 031ba55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/031ba55b6b474559dd8db6df5479416964e0dc30) (27 Mar 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48eee46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48eee46d6accbb6ef491f811fd9a9c72843d469b), 29 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`sparse-checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5644ca28cded68972c74614fc06d6e0e1db1a7de): provide a new reapply subcommand
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> If commands like merge or rebase materialize files as part of their work, or a previous sparse-checkout command failed to update individual files due to dirty changes, users may want a command to simply 'reapply' the sparsity rules.
>
> Provide one.

The [updated `git sparse-checkout` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5644ca28cded68972c74614fc06d6e0e1db1a7de/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt#L73-L81) now includes:

> ### `reapply`:

> Reapply the sparsity pattern rules to paths in the working tree.
>
> Commands like `merge` or `rebase` can materialize paths to do their work (e.g. in order to show you a conflict), and other sparse-checkout commands might fail to sparsify an individual file (e.g. because it has unstaged changes or conflicts).
>
> In such cases, it can make sense to run `git sparse-checkout reapply` later after cleaning up affected paths (e.g. resolving conflicts, undoing or committing changes, etc.).

---

But, with Git 2.27, it won't reapply/update itself using `git read-tree` anymore:

See [commit 5644ca2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5644ca28cded68972c74614fc06d6e0e1db1a7de), [commit 681c637](https://github.com/git/git/commit/681c637b4ae1c46c09edda62a1aed6eaa69a2649), [commit ebb568b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebb568b9e2539ce2dbb3853ff3d4869a5c690601), [commit 22ab0b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22ab0b37d85080d8932e992e183b2f86e67bff19), [commit 6271d77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6271d77cb1ccfb7e4124593b4463446fe1188cda), [commit 1ac83f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac83f42da6437d74098f162fcfa37474c94e223), [commit cd002c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd002c15611a995a29b9e5881745bba402d63952), [commit 4ee5d50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ee5d50fc39f8d41f67c3c9a936084fb914c9a50), [commit f56f31a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f56f31af0301f6446f8689ba1a997d74fb82f45f), [commit 7af7a25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7af7a25853cb87f34d192ba1d813ca09ee15d9f4), [commit 30e89c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30e89c12f0afc5c4382b531973a5e82b60d402bd), [commit 3cc7c50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cc7c50402ce1cbac9735da64844eb00bc096f46), [commit b0a5a12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a5a12a60393237f98ec4b0fcf2b7d3c3232a2a), [commit 72064ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72064ee578a59d4511cab17496c5246af02397f3), [commit fa0bde4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa0bde45cdebee8bac95e66e4bf5ba16c77fbdba), [commit d61633a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61633ae186d26ab2c216108c917ec0ae7dd2782), [commit d7dc1e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7dc1e1668fcbd5af019d0bc059b8dcb35743c86), [commit 031ba55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/031ba55b6b474559dd8db6df5479416964e0dc30) (27 Mar 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48eee46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48eee46d6accbb6ef491f811fd9a9c72843d469b), 29 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`unpack-trees`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7af7a25853cb87f34d192ba1d813ca09ee15d9f4): add a new `update_sparsity()` function
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> Previously, the only way to update the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bits for various paths was invoking `git read-tree -mu HEAD` or calling the same code that this codepath invoked.
>
> **This however had a number of problems if the index or working directory were not clean.**
>
> First, let's consider the case:
>
> ```
> Flipping SKIP_WORKTREE -> !SKIP_WORKTREE (materializing files)
> ```
>
> If the working tree was clean this was fine, but if there were files or directories or symlinks or whatever already present at the given path then the operation would abort with an error.
>
> Let's label this case for later discussion:
>
> - A) There is an untracked path in the way
>
> Now let's consider the opposite case:
>
> ```
> Flipping !SKIP_WORKTREE -> SKIP_WORKTREE (removing files)
> ```
>
> If the index and working tree was clean this was fine, but if there were any unclean paths we would run into problems.
>
> There are three different cases to consider:
>
> - B) The path is unmerged
> - C) The path has unstaged changes
> - D) The path has staged changes (differs from HEAD)
>
> If any path fell into case B or C, then the whole operation would be aborted with an error.
>
> With `sparse-checkout`, the whole operation would be aborted for case D as well, but for its predecessor of using `git read-tree -mu HEAD` directly, any paths that fell into case D would be removed from the working copy and the index entry for that path would be reset to match `HEAD` -- which looks and feels like data loss to users (only a few are even aware to ask whether it can be recovered, and even then it requires walking through loose objects trying to match up the right ones).
>
> Refusing to remove files that have unsaved user changes is good, but refusing to work on any other paths is very problematic for users.
>
> If the user is in the middle of a rebase or has made modifications to files that bring in more dependencies, then for their build to work they need to update the sparse paths.
>
> This logic has been preventing them from doing so.
>
> Sometimes in response, the user will stage the files and re-try, to no avail with sparse-checkout or to the horror of losing their changes if they are using its predecessor of `git read-tree -mu HEAD`.
>
> Add a new `update_sparsity()` function which will not error out in any of these cases but behaves as follows for the special cases:
>
> - A) Leave the file in the working copy alone, clear the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit, and print a warning (thus leaving the path in a state where status will report the file as modified, which seems logical).
> - B) Do NOT mark this path as `SKIP_WORKTREE`, and leave it as unmerged.
> - C) Do NOT mark this path as `SKIP_WORKTREE` and print a warning about the dirty path.
> - D) Mark the path as `SKIP_WORKTREE`, but do not revert the version stored in the index to match `HEAD`; leave the contents alone.
>
> I tried a different behavior for A (leave the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit set), but found it very surprising and counter-intuitive (e.g. the user sees it is present along with all the other files in that directory, tries to stage it, but [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) ignores it since the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit is set).
>
> A & C seem like optimal behavior to me.
>
> B may be as well, though I wonder if printing a warning would be an improvement.
>
> Some might be slightly surprised by D at first, but given that it does the right thing with `git commit` and even `git commit -a` (`git add` ignores entries that are marked `SKIP_WORKTREE` and thus doesn't delete them, and `commit -a` is similar), it seems logical to me.

And, still with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020):

See [commit 6c34239](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c34239de67e03390622dfad14d91ed3ce1048b5) (14 May 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fde4622](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fde4622c0866af528e6f2c4e6bb68d83b13695bf), 20 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`unpack-trees`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c34239de67e03390622dfad14d91ed3ce1048b5): also allow `get_progress()` to work on a different index
>
> <sup>Noticed-by: Jeff Hostetler</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> [commit b0a5a12a60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a5a12a60393237f98ec4b0fcf2b7d3c3232a2a) ("`unpack-trees`: allow `check_updates()` to work on a different index", 2020-03-27, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48eee46d6accbb6ef491f811fd9a9c72843d469b) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26)) allowed `check_updates()` to work on a different index, but it called `get_progress()` which was hardcoded to work on `o->result` much like `check_updates()` had been.
>
> Update it to also accept an index parameter and have `check_updates()` pass that parameter along so that both are working on the same index.

---

The code is more robust with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020):

See [commit 55fe225](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55fe225dde455ae32b9bc963bef4aabb9f5f7c3e), [commit 1c89001](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c890016a147536e4a6faa5664eedd8765a01b32), [commit 9a53219](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a53219f69bd470053cf93c3f4d2a77b6d4df3e5) (17 Aug 2020), and [commit f1de981](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1de981e8b6dedccf915095792c9afbe3c989591), [commit c514c62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c514c62a4fd8b4c4a3e2cad68fb590fce2940dc3), [commit 9101c8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9101c8ea2db466cce6d7d419d48e0516c6118813), [commit 8dc3156](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8dc3156373f4e02c1b1f657350ffae8ee94cbf44) (14 Aug 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 0d9a8e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0d9a8e33f9fd07efa10072576df01a9cae5d89e6), 27 Aug 2020)</sup>

> ### [`clear_pattern_list()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8dc3156373f4e02c1b1f657350ffae8ee94cbf44): clear embedded hashmaps
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> Commit [96cc8ab531](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96cc8ab5318cd57c8bc203b8f064b35883b2386f) ("`sparse-checkout`: use hashmaps for cone patterns", 2019-11-21, Git v2.25.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd72a08d6ce451e7d4725d6b3b411d482333e5cb)) added some auxiliary hashmaps to the `pattern_list` struct, but they're leaked when `clear_pattern_list()` is called.

---

Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), is clearer:

See [commit ecc7c88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecc7c8841de40a38637680509f7e1e6ce25d89ca) (25 Feb 2022), and [commit d79d299](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d79d29935262f8422a6e620bd33cc2fce28e669d), [commit 9023535](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690), [commit af6a518](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af6a51875a44c0bd16a21329456aadde615a2f46), [commit 26b5d6b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b5d6b0e56898a0284d0f45dd5a69f59257a6ab), [commit b3df8c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3df8c982a1bfb21b7803ca01d72951966505fb2) (14 Jan 2022) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 48609de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48609de3bf32befb69c40c1a2595a98dac0448b4) (13 Jan 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 82386b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82386b44963f127d6dbe25d48889bde3149e177c), 09 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`9023535bd3`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690):Update documentation related to sparsity and the `skip-worktree` bit
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> - Both `read-tree` and `update-index` tried to describe how to use the `skip-worktree` bit, but both predated the `sparse-checkout` command.
>   The `sparse-checkout` command is a far easier mechanism to use and for users trying to reduce the size of their working tree, we should recommend users to look at it instead.
> - The `update-index` documentation pointed out that assume-unchanged and `skip-worktree` sounded similar but had different purposes.
>   However, it made no attempt to explain the differences, only to point out that they were different.
>   Explain the differences.
> - The `update-index` documentation focused much more on (internal?) implementation details than on end-user usage.
>   Try to explain its purpose better for users of `update-index`, rather than fellow developers trying to work with the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit.
> - Clarify that when `core.sparseCheckout=true`, we treat a file's presence in the working tree as being an override to the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit (i.e.
>   in sparse checkouts when the file is present we ignore the `SKIP_WORKTREE` bit).

`git read-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690/Documentation/git-read-tree.txt#L378-L382):

> Note: The `update-index` and `read-tree` primitives for supporting the
> `skip-worktree` bit predated the introduction of
> [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout).  Users are encouraged to use
> `sparse-checkout` in preference to these low-level primitives.

`git sparse-checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt#L18-L31):

> This command is used to create sparse checkouts, which means that it
> changes the working tree from having all tracked files present, to only
> have a subset of them.  It can also switch which subset of files are
> present, or undo and go back to having all tracked files present in the
> working copy.
>
> The subset of files is chosen by providing a list of directories in
> cone mode (which is recommended), or by providing a list of patterns
> in non-cone mode.
>
> When in a sparse-checkout, other Git commands behave a bit differently.
> For example, switching branches will not update paths outside the
> sparse-checkout directories/patterns, and `git commit -a` will not record
> paths outside the sparse-checkout directories/patterns as deleted.

`git sparse-checkout` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690/Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt#L135-L142):

> "Sparse checkout" allows populating the working directory sparsely.  It
> uses the `skip-worktree` bit (see [`git` update-index``](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)) to tell Git
> whether a file in the working directory is worth looking at.
>
> If the
> `skip-worktree` bit is set, and the file is not present in the working tree,
> then its absence is ignored.
>
> Git will avoid populating the contents of
> those files, which makes a sparse checkout helpful when working in a
> repository with many files, but only a few are important to the current
> user.

`git` update-index`` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L399-L425):

> `skip-worktree` bit can be defined in one (long) sentence: Tell git to
> avoid writing the file to the working directory when reasonably
> possible, and treat the file as unchanged when it is not
> present in the working directory.
>
> Note that not all git commands will pay attention to this bit, and
> some only partially support it.
>
> The `update-index` flags and the `read-tree` capabilities relating to the
> `skip-worktree` bit predated the introduction of the
> [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) command, which provides a much easier
> way to configure and handle the `skip-worktree` bits.  If you want to
> reduce your working tree to only deal with a subset of the files in
> the repository, we strongly encourage the use of
> [`git sparse-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) in preference to the low-level
> `update-index` and `read-tree` primitives.
>
> The primary purpose of the `skip-worktree` bit is to enable sparse
> checkouts, i.e. to have working directories with only a subset of
> paths present.
>
> When the `skip-worktree` bit is set, Git commands (such
> as `switch`, `pull`, `merge`) will avoid writing these files.
>
> However, these commands will sometimes write these files anyway in
> important cases such as conflicts during a merge or rebase.
> Git
> commands will also avoid treating the lack of such files as an
> intentional deletion; for example `git add -u` will not not stage a
> deletion for these files and `git commit -a` will not make a commit
> deleting them either.

`git` update-index`` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9023535bd3953df265f30a3d53b1fda2107bb690/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L428-L439):

> The assume-unchanged bit is for leaving the file in the
> working tree but having Git omit checking it for changes and presuming
> that the file has not been changed (though if it can determine without
> stat'ing the file that it has changed, it is free to record the
> changes).
>
> `skip-worktree` tells Git to ignore the absence of the file,
> avoid updating it when possible with commands that normally update
> much of the working directory (e.g. `checkout`, `switch`, `pull`,
> etc.), and not have its absence be recorded in commits.
>
> Note that in
> sparse checkouts (setup by `git sparse-checkout` or by configuring
> `core.sparseCheckout` to true), if a file is marked as `skip-worktree` in
> the index but is found in the working tree, Git will clear the
> `skip-worktree` bit for that file.