# Git sparse checkout error "Entry 'path/to/file' not update. Cannot update sparse checkout"

Tags: git, sparse-checkout, git-sparse-checkout

I've just done a sparse checkout following the steps below

```
git clone http://location/repo.git
# create .git/info/sparse-checkout file
git config --bool core.sparsecheckout true
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

Unfortunately the final step fails with the error message

```
Entry 'path/to/file' not update. Cannot update sparse checkout
```

Which is strange because (1) `path/to/file` exists (2) the sparse checkout process succeeded on another machine git version 1.7.1 (Centos 6). The current machine is a Centos 7 box with git version 1.8.3.1 installed. The output of `git config --list` is identical on both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem essentially by removing all the files and repeating the same steps. It has been [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148579/why-do-excluded-files-keep-reappearing-in-my-git-sparse-checkout#comment57642870_33814937) that this could be a bug in git, or IMO some sort of file corruption.

Another solution that worked for me (YMMV). Try repeatedly checking out and the problematic directory and running `git read-tree`

1. git checkout -- path/
2. git read-tree -mu HEAD

Comment: git checkout -- ./
git read-tree -mu HEAD        after this my folder is empty !  where is my file ?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs (for files that are in the work-tree) if function `ie_match_stat` fails to match the stat info.  This particular call to `ie_match_stat` passes `CE_MATCH_IGNORE_VALID|CE_MATCH_IGNORE_SKIP_WORKTREE` as `ie_match_stat` would normally obey the cache entry flags `CE_VALID` or `CE_SKIP_WORKTREE` by saying: *the work-tree copy is up to date* even if it's not.  The sparse checkout code uses the skip-worktree flag (`CE_SKIP_WORKTREE`) to mark files that should *not* be checked out, so that the rest of Git won't complain about them being missing.

Hence, the oddities here are:

- The skip-worktree bit is set on a file that *is* in the work-tree.  Why?
- The index entry's cached `stat` data for the this file do not match the `lstat` results from this file.  Why?

The answer to the first question could be: *because a user set it* (using `git update-index`).  The answer to the second could be: *because a user modified the file*.  So they're not particularly odd at all, they just imply that the file does not match whatever was created by an initial checkout or `git read-tree` operation.  If you don't care about losing the contents of the file, feel free to remove it.  If you do care about the contents, clear the skip-worktree bit (`git update-index --no-skip-worktree`), after which `git diff` should show what's different.

There may well be some bugs in this area, especially in Git versions that are this ancient (Git 1.8.x—current Git is 2.22).

Comment: The problem's happened again. Same repo different checkout `git diff` returns a boatload of messages `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in path/to/file` and `The file will have its original line endings in your working directory`. `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` remove the errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), once you have remove the files, you can use [`git sparse-checkout reapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515444/6309)

Second, the error message has changed (still with Git 2.27+):

See [commit 5644ca2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5644ca28cded68972c74614fc06d6e0e1db1a7de), [commit 681c637](https://github.com/git/git/commit/681c637b4ae1c46c09edda62a1aed6eaa69a2649), [commit ebb568b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebb568b9e2539ce2dbb3853ff3d4869a5c690601), [commit 22ab0b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22ab0b37d85080d8932e992e183b2f86e67bff19), [commit 6271d77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6271d77cb1ccfb7e4124593b4463446fe1188cda), [commit 1ac83f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ac83f42da6437d74098f162fcfa37474c94e223), [commit cd002c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd002c15611a995a29b9e5881745bba402d63952), [commit 4ee5d50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ee5d50fc39f8d41f67c3c9a936084fb914c9a50), [commit f56f31a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f56f31af0301f6446f8689ba1a997d74fb82f45f), [commit 7af7a25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7af7a25853cb87f34d192ba1d813ca09ee15d9f4), [commit 30e89c1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30e89c12f0afc5c4382b531973a5e82b60d402bd), [commit 3cc7c50](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cc7c50402ce1cbac9735da64844eb00bc096f46), [commit b0a5a12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b0a5a12a60393237f98ec4b0fcf2b7d3c3232a2a), [commit 72064ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72064ee578a59d4511cab17496c5246af02397f3), [commit fa0bde4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa0bde45cdebee8bac95e66e4bf5ba16c77fbdba), [commit d61633a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61633ae186d26ab2c216108c917ec0ae7dd2782), [commit d7dc1e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7dc1e1668fcbd5af019d0bc059b8dcb35743c86), [commit 031ba55](https://github.com/git/git/commit/031ba55b6b474559dd8db6df5479416964e0dc30) (27 Mar 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 48eee46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48eee46d6accbb6ef491f811fd9a9c72843d469b), 29 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`unpack-trees`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22ab0b37d85080d8932e992e183b2f86e67bff19): make sparse path messages sound like warnings
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> The messages for problems with sparse paths are phrased as errors that cause the operation to abort, even though we are not making the operation abort.
>
> Reword the messages to make sense in their new context.

This is no longer:

> ```
> Cannot update sparse checkout
> ```

But:

> ```
> The following paths are not up to date
> ```