# Remove files from git repository without cloning it

Tags: git, bitbucket

For some reason a repository on Bitbucket that I need to clone contains very large files that I don't require.

Is it possible to clone this repository without these files ?
Or maybe is it possible to delete these files without cloning the repo in the first place?

Comment: If those large files are not present in the tip of the branch of interest, you could do a shallow clone; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial

Comment: They are, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

With git you cannot easily clone partially a repository
But with bitbucket, you can delete directly a file from the website

1. Open Bitbucket and go to the dashboard of your repo
2. Click on `Source`
3. Select your branch
4. Click on the file that you want delete
5. Near of `Edit` button, select the arrow, and then `Delete`
6. Edit the commit message
7. [OPTIONNAL] You can create a pull request
8. Validate your commit
9. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I click on the file, it automatically download it. I can only remove text files that open directly in Bitbucket editor.

Comment: Effectively, it does not work for file which can not be open by Bitbucket
I'll search and say the solution if I found something =)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no EDIT button for me :( I guess I don't have enough rights