# git clone only files with a specific extension

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to only clone files with a particular extension? For eg. only clone .sh files?

I know that I can clone the whole thing and then delete the remaining files, but I dont want to be wasteful.Thanks!

Comment: `git clone` operates on entire repositories, not on individual files.

Comment: Use sparse checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial)