# Clone specific file types using git clone

Tags: git

Is it possible to git clone specific resource type? I'd like to clone only .resx file types from git repository. Can I apply any filter for:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/.../test.git
```

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288192/git-clone-only-files-with-a-specific-extension

Comment: @Backtrack oh sorry I was looking for an answer but didn't see this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can not do that in clone. Please have a look into this links 
[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)
and [Partial clone with Git and Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial)